# How to get the first element and not its children() on jquery in a .on("click") function?

Tags: jquery, click, children

I have this gallery slider plugin called LightSlider that I just got a few days in the internet, and I've added some legend bars floating in the bottom of the image, so I was trying to make the fullscreen click button to be the image, and not the legend bars I've made. When I click in the image nothing happens, but when I click in the legend bars I've added the gallery plugin shows up in full screen.

So I noticed that it's happening thanks to the `$(this).children()` that I found on the responsible line for the fullscreen call.

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
$children.on('click', function (e) {
    if (settings.selector !== null) {
        $children = $(settings.selector);
    } else {
        $children = $this.children();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    index = $children.index(this);
    prevIndex = index;
    setUp.init(index);
});
```

The thing is that when I changed the first line `$children.on('click')` to `$('img:first-child').on('click')` it worked to make the image call the fullscreen and not the legend bars, but then everytime I go on fullscreen the initial image is the same, and not the one that I clicked.

**Obs.: The images in the gallery are all listed by a loop on php**

The `$children.index(this)` is what I believe to be the responsible for the initial image on fullscreen...

Is there anything I should put to replace this code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).closest($children).length > 0)
        e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't seem to work. Now the click simply does nothing